# Why there are 256 different control sequences of length 2 and 256^2 of length 3 in TeX?

Tags: tex-core

On page 11 of the book **The TeXbook**, there is a question:

> How many diﬀerent control sequences of length 2 (including the escape character) are possible? How many of length 3?

The answer is:

> There are 256 of length 2; most of these are undeﬁned when TEX begins. (TEX allows any character to be an escape, but it does not distinguish between control sequences that start with diﬀerent escape characters.) If we assume that there are 52 letters, there are exactly 522 possible control sequences of length 3 (one for each pair of letters, from AA to zz). But Chapter 7 explains how to use \catcode to change any character into a “letter”; therefore it’s possible to use any of 256^2 potential control sequences of length 3.

How is this 256 calculated and how is the 256^2?  I can't understand the answer.

Comment: @campa How did you know TeX understands 8 bit ASCII?

Comment: it does not have to be ASCII but everything about  characters in classic tex is based on 0-255 character numbers. input and fonts

Comment: for luatex or xetex of course none of this applies and there are far far more allowable control sequences

Comment: @DavidCarlisle On page 43, it says it uses ASCII.

Comment: A friendly piece of advice: a wise man (@DavidCarlisle `:-)`) told me once that the TeXbook is written so that first you have to understand TeX and the read the TeXbook to understand what it was telling you. Jokes aside, if you stop at every sentence you don't understand immediately, it'll take you ages. Sometimes it's better to keep reading and going back when needed.

Comment: I tried but it is very confusing too. @campa

Comment: @Y.zeng technically ASCII is a 7 bit encoding with just 128 characters, tex is 8 bit with 256, but the textbook on many things does not spell out details in early chapters.  The fact that character codes are 0+255 is explicit everywhere in tex syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that there are 256 2-letter sequences, and 256×256 three letter sequences is just a consequence that in classic TeX (and pdfTeX) a character code is a number betweeen 0 and 255.  So there are 256 names of length 1 and 256×256 names of length 2 (each preceded by an escape character).

The 255 upper limit of character codes is explicit everywhere in tex syntax such as `\char` or `\mathchar`.

If you try `\char256` in tex or pdftex You will get an error

```
! Bad character code (256).
l.3 \char256
            
? h
A character number must be between 0 and 255.
I changed this one to zero.

?
```

In xetex or luatex, 255 above needs to be replaced by the largest Unicode value which is hex 10FFFF = decimal 1114111  so there are 1114112 codes  0-1114111  and 114112×114112=1241245548544 three character sequences including the escape character.

with luatex you get

```
! Bad character code (1114112).
l.7 \char"110000
              
? h
A character code must be between 0 and 1114111.
I changed this one to zero.
?
```

from `\char"110000`

Comment: Thanks. May you tell me, 1) why the maximum hex is 10FFFF? 2) Why you add quota between `\char` and `110000`? In your first example, you use `\char256`, but in your second example, you use `\char"110000`.

Comment: @Y.zeng a double quote `"` is tex syntax for hexadecimal, so `\char256` could be written `\char"FF`  and `\char"110000` could be written `\char1114112` it's the same thing.  But especially for larger numbers hex is easier, as it is easier to see the significance of  hex 110000 than decimal 1114112 even though they are the same number. Unicode is an international standard and the fact that it defines an encoding from 0 to hex 10FFFF  is just a fact of the definition, like asking why the English alphabet has 26 letters. It just is that way.

Comment: I thought about this question for a while. Unicode is so limited, how should the characters be expressed if they exceed unicode? I used to think that unicode was infinite.

Comment: @Y.zeng limited??  1114112  is a big number, and that is just base characters these can be combined with combining characters to add accents, or affect the skin colour on emoji or use complicated text combinations for Indic scripts. Only a very small fraction of that range is allocated so far.

Comment: Okay. It turns out we have so limited characters in the world.

Comment: @Y.zeng if you find a character not in Unicode there is a process to have it added, and then it will be assigned a unicode number. At the present rate of adding characters it will be some centuries before they run out of numbers and have to consider moving to a larger encoding.